# Add image instead of string title to react-native-segmented-control-tab

Tags: android, ios, react-native, npm, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using [react-native-segmented-control-tab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-segmented-control-tab) in my project and it works fine. Below is my current code

```
<SegmentedControlTab
                tabsContainerStyle={styles.tabsContainerStyle}
                tabStyle={styles.tabStyle}
                activeTabStyle={styles.activeTabStyle}
                values={["First", "Second", "Third"]}
                selectedIndex={this.state.selectedIndex}
                onTabPress={this.handleIndexChange}
              />
```

This displays segment with title string "First, Second and Third". Now instead of these strings, I would like to replace them with images. Is that possible? How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this (only works on Android...) by looking into the source code of the [@react-native-community/segmented-control](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/segmented-control) library (version '^2.2.1') - file 'SegmentedControlTab.js' line 84.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  style={styles.container}
  disabled={!enabled}
  onPress={onSelect}>
  <View style={[styles.default]}>
    {typeof value === 'number' || typeof value === 'object' ? (
      <Image source={value} style={styles.segmentImage} />
    ) : isBase64(value) ? (
      <Image source={{uri: value}} style={styles.segmentImage} />
    ) : (
      <Text style={[idleStyle, selected && activeStyle]}>{value}</Text>
    )}
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This is the code that renders each of the text values passed in. As you can see, if you pass in a `number` or an `object` (such as `{uri: 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/papirus-team/papirus-apps/256/albion-online-icon.png'}`) the library will render an `<Image />` element. You can also send a Base64 encoded image, and it will render an `<Image />`.

If you pass in something that is neither a number, object nor a Base64 string, the library renders a `<Text>` element.

Example below:

```
    <SegmentedControl
      values={['data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAA7klEQVQ4T92Uvw6CQAzGvzPRxNXkNOCiz8Do5Is7uvEIhkkwnnF00AFTkpJayh8TJlg40q8fv7Z35zDy40b2w8QM95EvZYuyIjQqNEvmRCuBDLvinYZ9A/uH8AVg2WZIRkQ5c+5wye9nqasJkwTzZ+7fHCyBqwO2kkKWuov9yZU4kn4Vh0Wa4kPrylA3W5GFrAhr1jGdRU+xCp2CTELfnKTfrNMaCVUZSjOZpCkknV6zqWnYVo61ZTRQo2Q2k0L9AyvGrfsZilW6RWv1nVtVbxs16UdWBN+1sfeRvwHYsIZhJnbb9J3t+qQMEQ7VfAGjuKJN2bFKJQAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==', {uri: 'https://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/papirus-team/papirus-apps/256/albion-online-icon.png'}]}
      style={segmentControlStyles.container}
      selectedIndex={accessByIndex}
      onChange={onAccessByChange}
      backgroundColor={mainColors.segmentBackground}
      fontStyle={segmentControlStyles.text}
    />
```

Result:

[image: Segmented control with images - example]

P.S.
This solution works on Android only... I haven't found a way to make it work on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I created a fork using the react-native-segmented-control module and incorporated support for including both text and images, following this format:

fork address : https://github.com/amirbhz86/segmented-control

> <SegmentedControl
> selectedIndex={0}
> values={[ require('./add.png'), require('./add.png'), require('./add.png)]}
> iconTexts={["One", "Two", "Three"]}   />